# How to remove comments from transpiled code using babel-cli

Tags: javascript, babeljs

I've been looking around for some `.babelrc` option to remove comments from the transpiled code, but I haven't had any luck. I tried this:

```
{
  "comments": false
}
```

as well as

```
{
  "options": {
    "comments": false
  }
}
```

and neither works. I'm out of ideas, and I was unable to find any decent documentation anywhere.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Using `.babelrc` is always recommended:

```
{
  comments: false
}
```

If using `babel-cli`, you can use the `--no-comments` options to achieve the same behaviour.

The latest version of `babel-cli` includes [tests that check for this behaviour to be implemented correctly](https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/master/packages/babel-cli/test/fixtures/babel/filename%20babelrc%20no%20comments).

---

**EDIT**

It does look like a problem with babel CLI ignoring the comments in `.babelrc` , a workaround is to use the `--no-comments` option.

In your `package.json`

```
"build": "babel ./index.js --out-dir ./dist/index.js --no-comments"
```

To know all the options of babel-cli

```
./node_modules/.bin/babel -h
```

---

**ORIGINAL**

Where are you running babel from? Gulp?

Check that you have the `.babelrc` file in the same or a parent directory of the files beign transpiled

From [babeljs.io](http://babeljs.io/docs/usage/babelrc/):

> Babel will look for a .babelrc in the current directory of the file
>   being transpiled. If one does not exist, it will travel up the
>   directory tree until it finds either a .babelrc, or a package.json
>   with a "babel": {} hash within.

I have a project with this structure:

- dist

  - index.js
- .babelrc
- index.js
- gulpfile.js
- node_modules

  - ...

The relevant task in `gulpfile.js`

```
gulp.task('babel', () => {
    return gulp.src('index.js')
        .pipe(babel({
            presets: ['es2015']
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'));
});
```

Contents of `.babelrc`

```
{
    "comments": false
}
```

The comments are being succesfully removed.

Also check if you're not setting the `comments` option to true in your gulpfile, for example.

Comment: I'm running babel from my own `npm run build` script, which is just doing `babel ./src --out-dir ./lib`. I tried putting `"comments": false` in `.babelrc` but nothing happened.

Comment: where is the .babelrc file in that directory structure?

Comment: At the project root.

Comment: The .babelrc is definitely working, because it's loading presets/plugins just fine.

Comment: Ok , let me try to replicate that then.

Comment: Well that was easy to replicate! :) `npm init -f; npm i --save-dev babel-cli`, make a `.babelrc` with comments set to false, then transpile something.

Comment: Yup, the comments are still there. Looks like a problem with the CLI version of babel.

Comment: Hot damn .. teamwork! :) I'll report it as a bug. Thanks!

Comment: Found a fix!! add --no-comments to your build script in `package.json` like this: `"build": "babel ./index.js --out-dir ./dist/index.js --no-comments"` run `./node_modules/.bin/babel -h` to find more about the CLI

Comment: Yep, I knew about the command line option. I was just trying to keep everything in .babelrc.

Comment: @cheesyeyes This issue appears to be solved in the latest version of babel-cli

Comment: this answer also works if you're using  `babel.config.json`

Comment: doesn't seem to work for removing licenses :/ - some unwanted licenses are appearing due to tslib etc - license that isn't in source code