# Babel remove comment blocks in js files

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, vue-cli

This is my **babel.config.js**:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ["@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset"],
  plugins: [
    [
      "search-and-replace",
      {
        rules: [
          {
            search: /(?:\/\*(?:[^\*]|\**[^\*\/])*\*+\/)|(?:\/\/[\S ]*)/,
            replace: "",
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  ],
};
```

I used [babel-plugin-search-and-replace](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-search-and-replace) to replace characters.

My goal is to remove comments from js files, for example:
[image]
I don't want the user could see the package description in the source codes. I tried other plugins and didn't succeed.

Thanks for your helping.

Comment: _"I don't want the user could see the package description in the source codes."_: why not? And your average user isn't going to be pouring over your source code. They just want the site to work.

Comment: @Andy has a fair point there. If you still want to remove comments, check out this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38211107/9636400

Comment: @Andy The Employer wants this :(

Comment: Use the babel config `comments: false`. Refer: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/options#comments

Comment: ```comments: false``` not working @Satya 
@Andy

Comment: @ShaSha Could you share your updated babel config. and how are you running babel? Is it through the CLI or NPM scripts?

Comment: @SatyaS Project created by vue-cli

Answer (score 0):

Solved by webpack:

```
  chainWebpack: (config) => {
    config.optimization.minimizer("terser").tap((args) => {
      args[0].terserOptions.output = {
        ...args[0].terserOptions.output,
        comments: false, // exclude all comments from output
      };
      return args;
    });
  },
```